# Generics and reflection in Java. Classes

Tags: java, reflection

I have a task where I have to implement method of creating object of the given class.

```
class Paper {}

class Bakery {}

class Cake extends Bakery {}

class ReflexiveBaker {
  
  /**
   * Create bakery of the provided class.
   * 
   * @param order class of bakery to create
   * @return bakery object
   */
  public Object bake(Class order) {
    // Add implementation here
  }
  
}
```

How should I implement this method correctly? I tried to do it in this way

```
public <T extends Bakery> T bake(Class<T> order) {
        try {
            return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But it always throws NoSuchMethodException. Moreover, from the task "﻿It's guaranteed that all subclasses of Bakery will have public parameterless constructor."
And InvocationTargetException is not imported in the task so it should be implemented without it. What's the problem?

Comment: Cake cake = reflexiveBaker.bake(Cake.class);

Comment: However, I just solved the problem. Added throws ReflectiveOperationException and changed implementation to "return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();"

Comment: How to understand that I can replace four exceptions by only one when IntelliJ idea hints provide these four?

Comment: Please stop asking more questions in comments. You should really visit the [help] to understand how this place works. If you got an answer that solves your problem, then accept that answer. If you found the solution yourself, and it is not trivial, consider to write a self answer. But please dont come in give more/different information/requests within comments.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how to do it. You have to use `getDeclaredConstructor()`

```
class Paper {
}

class Bakery {
}

class Cake extends Bakery {
}

class ReflexiveBaker {

    /**
     * Create bakery of the provided class.
     *
     * @param order class of bakery to create
     * @return bakery object
     */
    public static <T extends Bakery> T bake(Class<T> order) {
        try {
            return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to instantiate class of type " + order, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cake cake = ReflexiveBaker.bake(Cake.class);
    System.out.println(cake.getClass());
}
```

Comment: The questioner wrote “*It's guaranteed that all subclasses of Bakery will have public parameterless constructor*”, but the classes aren’t public, hence, the default constructor is non-public as well. With truly public constructors, as “guaranteed”, you can use `getConstructor()` instead of `getDeclaredConstructor()`. But the most irritating aspect of this solution is that the question’s code already uses `getDeclaredConstructor()`, so you solved the problem without actually changing anything. Replacing a qualified `catch` by a generic `catch(Exception e)` is not an improvement.

Comment: @Holger my answer was published before the author changing his code. Please read carefully the comments before commenting

Comment: @Holger This is the comment: However, I just solved the problem. Added throws ReflectiveOperationException and changed implementation to "return order.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();" – qwoke yesterday

Comment: And the question doesn’t have a “throws ReflectiveOperationException”. And it [clearly has never been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65086111/revisions). In other words, you didn’t even read the question, just found an apparent solution in a comment and reposted it as answer, without re-checking? No further discussion needed…